# pipenv: RuntimeError Failed to lock Pipfile.lock

Tags: python, django, pip, pipfile

I'm getting this error when doing a `pipenv install`:

```
$ pipenv install mysqlclient
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!
```

How can I fix this?

```
demo) chandanm@Chandans-MacBook-Air demo % pipenv install mysqlclient
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Installing mysqlclient...
Resolving mysqlclient...
Added mysqlclient to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (e35515) out of date, updating to (537503)...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠴ Locking...False
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:Getting requirements to build wheel exited with 1
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 645, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 612, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:       ^^^^^^^^
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 592, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 908, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, internal_resolver = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 681, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 442, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv run pip install <requirement_name> to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the versions actually installed in the virtualenv.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Getting requirements to build wheel exited with 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 58, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 92, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 209, in install
    do_install(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 297, in do_install
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 281, in do_install
    do_init(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 648, in do_init
    do_lock(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/routines/lock.py", line 65, in do_lock
    venv_resolve_deps(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 849, in venv_resolve_deps
    c = resolve(cmd, st, project=project)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 718, in resolve
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!")
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!
```

Comment: it worked. what I did was, I tried to install the previous version of mysqlclient. that is pipenv install mysqlclient==2.1.1

and it worked.